# Can I use 2 different row index- (i, ii) in one command?

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

I have dataset with dependencies between individual features and feature group. The individual features (f) can be further distinguished into main and side features (f.type). The expression of the main feature (f.type_exp) of a group determines if all other features of the group (except the main feature) are valid or not.

The task is to check for each id and f.group if the individual features of a given group are valid (valid based on the main feature expression) or not. Instead of looping over each id and ech group i am looking for a data.table solution. Following this, i use one row index (i) to check if the argument is true or not, and then a second row index (ii) to update the values of a feature.

## The data looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(id= c(rep("id1",3), rep("id2",1)) ,
                f=c("a1","a2","b1", "b1"), 
                f.group= c(rep("a",3), "b"),
                f.type= c("main", "side", "side", "main"),
                f.type_exp = c(TRUE, NA, NA, FALSE))

d
#   id  f f.group f.type f.type_exp
#  id1 a1       a   main       TRUE
#  id1 a2       a   side         NA
#  id1 b1       a   side         NA
#  id2 b1       b   main      FALSE
```

#the solution for one id + group combination could be soemthing like this:

### define steps

```
group_1 <- d[id=="id1" & f.group=="a",]
#(i)
step1 <- group_1[f.type=="main", f.type_exp]==T
#(ii)
step2 <- group_1[f.type=="side", f:= NA]

print(step2)
```

Preferred solutions in one line (does Not work)

```
#i = f.type=="main"& f.type_exp==T
  #used to determine truth (if (f.type=="main"& f.type_exp==T) == T )

#ii = f[f.type=="side"]
  #used to update values in f according to index of f.type
```

```
test1 <- d[f.type=="main"& f.type_exp==T,  f[f.type=="side"]:= NA,  by=.(id, f.group)]
```

#ALternative Solution So far my solution is to use the following function:

```
my_fun <- function(x){
  if( x[f.type=="main", f.type_exp]==T ){
    x$f[x$f.type=="side"] <- NA  
  }
  return(x)
}


test  <- d[, my_fun(.SD), by = .(id, f.group)]

test

#   id f.group    f f.type f.type_exp
#  id1       a   a1   main       TRUE
#  id1       a <NA>   side         NA
#  id1       a <NA>   side         NA
#  id2       b   b1   main      FALSE
```

Expected outcome: the function my_fun produces the expected output. all features of type side of group id1 are set to NA because the main feature expression is true. group id2 remains unchanged since the main feature expression is false, thus in this example it does not cotnain any side features that could be updated.

however, i am sure there is a better data table based solution to this task

## Question:

1. Is there a solution where i use 2 different index (i and ii) as described in Preferred solutions ?
2. is my general reasoning correct that data.table grouping operator by =.(id, f.group) should be used to avoid looping over both arguments
3. should another library be considered? ( i want to point out that the original dataset contains millions of rows)

Thanks for any hints in advance!

Comment: I'm having trouble following the logic.  Can you show the expected output? If your data table `d` was processed correctly, what would the outcome look like?

Comment: None of your logic requires `by=` grouping. A good rule-of-thumb for when you may want to group with `by=` is when you are using an aggregating function (e.g., `sum`, `mean`, `any`, `all`) or counting function (e.g., `seq_along`) or such; there are certainly many other times when grouping is useful/required. Please provide explicit expected output given this sample data. (Do you just need `d[id == 'id1' & f.group == 'a' & (f.type == 'side' | (f.type == 'main' & f.type_exp)), f := NA]`?)

Comment: @Paul Stafford Allen I have now changed my question to include a reference to the expected results. Thanks for this hint! I hope my question is now better understandable.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your comment- helps me to better understand what method i should use for a given problem! So when cleaning data - as in this task, which involves filtering out side features that were entered incorrectly - using the grouping function is not recommended. I wanted to use it instead of 2 loops, one to loop over each ID and one to loop over each feature group. i agree with you that the group function is particularly useful for aggregation task still i hoped i extand it to filtering tasks. can you recommand an alternative like a dplyr approach or the good old for loop?

Comment: If the filtering requires the use of any aggregating function, `by=` is justified. It is not a "recommendation" to not use it when filtering, it is entirely based on the logic being calculated in the `j=` portion.